# Python Dictionary - List Nesting

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a key and a pair of values, the values are stored in a List. But i'm keeping the list empty so i can .append its values ,i cant seem to be able to do this

```
>>>myDict = {'Numbers':[]}
>>>myDict['Numbers'[1].append(user_inputs)
```

doesn't seem to work, returns an error . How do i refer to the list in myDict so i can append its values.

Also is it possible to have a dictionary inside a list and also have another list inside? if so? what is its syntax or can you recommend anyother way i can do this

```
>>>myDict2 = {'Names': [{'first name':[],'Second name':[]}]}
```

do i change the second nested list to a tuple?? Please lets keep it to PYTHON 2.7

Comment: I assume you're learning python. It is best if you learn python 3, there are countless improvements, and you'll encounter less problems.

Comment: Yes but it was recommended i use 2.7 as it is the "only stable version" as ive heard

Comment: That was perhaps the case 5 years ago. Now python 3 is the preferred version.

Comment: Since you said 5 years, i guess i have to change. I hate being outdated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error because your syntax is wrong. The following appends to the list value for the `'Numbers'` key:

```
myDict['Numbers'].append(user_inputs)
```

You can nest Python objects arbitrarily; your `myDict2` syntax is entirely correct. Only the *keys* need to be immutable (so a tuple vs. a list), but your keys are all strings:

```
>>> myDict2 = {'Names': [{'first name':[],'Second name':[]}]}
>>> myDict2['Names']
[{'first name': [], 'Second name': []}]
>>> myDict2['Names'][0]
{'first name': [], 'Second name': []}
>>> myDict2['Names'][0]['first name']
[]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers it was very helpful. But I was just wandering if there was a way to loop raw_input for a number of times ..i dont want to define each raw_input for like 50 times as my dictionary would require. I was thinking of a for loop, but i,m entirely new to python and its a tad different from java

Comment: @DamilolaLucasAromiwe: you can make a loop with `for counter in range(50):` for example; generally speaking things are easier in Python than they are in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You should access the list with `myDict['Numbers']`:

```
>>>myDict['Numbers'].append(user_inputs)
```

---

You can have dicts inside of a list.

The only catch is that dictionary keys have to be immutable, so you can't have dicts or lists as keys.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library, which supports a mix of nested dictionaries and lists.

In addition, you may also be interested in the setdefault method of the [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict) class.

Format is something like:

```
new_dict = dict()
some_list = ['1', '2', '3', ...]
for idx, val in enumerate(some_list):
    something = get_something(idx)
    new_dict.setdefault(val, []).append(something)
```

Comment: You stopped speaking English from the third line. is idx a placeholder like some_list or a python statement?

Comment: idx is short-hand for index.  The [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function within python allows you to iterate over something (i.e. some_list) and get back both the "count"/index and the actual value.